# How to preview files from local storage in React JS version 18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, libraries, preview

I am currently working with a React application that can upload documents, and the files would be stored in the local project directory. I want to add preview functionality where all sorts of uploaded files (jpg,png, pdf, doc, docx, xls, xlsx) can be shown and rendered accordingly, but most of the react libraries I stumbled upon cannot access the files locally (e.g., react-doc-viewer). Some are also deprecated and are not compatible with the current application's React version 18 (e.g., react-file-viewer). Thus, would you have any recommendations on what options I could have, perhaps specific libraries that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

React-doc-viewer has an option to view files locally (https://github.com/cyntler/react-doc-viewer#basic <- see the second array item in example code).

More examples with docx and xlsx here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-doc-viewer-demo-zvk4j

Comment: Hi @himanreddy, unfortunately viewing of local files with react-doc-viewer only works for pdf and image files but not for file extensions supported by microsoft such as doc, doc, xls, and xlsx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).